# Can I build this quiz client app?

Tags: android, mobile

I've been programming for over 20 years, but mostly in the VB and SQL.  As a side job, I host game shows at local bars and restaurants (Trivia, name that tune, etc.) and I'd like to develop an android app that I can install on mobile devices to give to customers to interact with the game.

I'm trying to make the game shows more interactive than just pen and paper (and time-consuming, manual scoring).  I can get Kindle Fires for $40 each, so I thought it would be cool to create an app that will allow the user to do 3 things:

- Choose an answer from a list (Multiple choice), and everyone can answer
- Buzz in (blocking other users out)
- type in an answer

I'd like the tablets to send the responses to a central "hub" or application that will record the answers so it can automatically do the scoring for me.  If possible, I'd prefer to be able to have everything connect through an ad hoc wifi network that I would set up on site (that part I know how to do, too).

I'm not looking to have the questions appear on the phone at this point; I have an office-based application that automates a powerpoint presentation based on questions/answers and other parameters imported from a database/spreadsheet.  (VBA is nice and easy for me.)

Ideally, the quiz questions would work like this:

1. I project the answer where everyone can see it.
2. After announcing the questions, the tablet apps are "activated" and
   the user can then select their A, B, C or D answer (or buzz in, or
   type an answer depending the type of questions/quiz).
3. My hub application would then receive the following information:
   team/player name, answer choice, time it took to answer the question
   (because I'm thinking of using a points tier that gives faster
   players get more points, either based on time ).

The catch is, I don't even know where to begin from an android development standpoint, as I have no experience in that realm.  In most programming cases, I know keywords to search on, but I'm totally flying blind here.

Does this seem like a feasibly application?  There are systems online that I can buy, but the buzzers are expensive and the software has some significant limitations that prevent me from spending the money.  I'd rather develop something myself and spend $40 per client unit and load it up with my software.

(Then, of course, license the whole kit and kaboodle and make a mint and retire in 5 years, living the good life off of my pub quiz empire...)

So, if you have any suggestions on starting points, or specific methods and processes to being fiddling with, an IDE...any help would be greatly appreciated.  Once I'm up and running, I will reward you with extra points if you ever come to one of my events.

Comment: "Does this seem like a feasibly application?" -- what aspects concern you? From your description, my concerns are "does Android handle ad-hoc WiFi?", "can I replace the launcher on a Kindle Fire to prevent patrons from messing with the tablets?", and "does a pub really want to give possibly-drunk customers pieces of kit (tablets) that might wander off with them and are not necessarily liquid-resistant (for all sorts of possible liquids)?" Little of that has anything to do with programming, though.

Answer (score -1):

Go full kotlin !

Android works well with Kotlin and you can have a server quickly setup with : https://start.spring.io/#!language=kotlin

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-android.html

A good client for Android is provided here :
https://github.com/square/retrofit

You will probably have hard time to get started. Using same language for every part of the system will make things easier.

Also, Kotlin is less verbose than Java and will prevent you to make the usual mistakes found in Java world.

Also, if you create an open source project out of it, you may be eligible for IntelliJ.

Your very first stop is : http://try.kotlinlang.org/#/Examples/Hello,%20world!/Simplest%20version/Simplest%20version.kt

Get to know the language by trying it out. When you are in ease with it, start looking at Anko (https://github.com/Kotlin/anko).

To do the project in an easy way, break it down in milestones.

- Simple app which shows 4 buttons (choices) and shows a message for each button. (Eg. you clicked "1")
- Small server with spring boot. It should display whatever you post to it. (An "echo" server)
- Improvement of the simple app to POST something to the server and display the answer in a dialog.

At that point, you application is practically done! You would have understood enough to complete it. The hardest thing would be behind.

Don't think your are smarter than the flock. Do these milestones, at least. You will be thankful to yourself.

This post may seems unrelated, but I explain how good Kotlin can be in such projects : https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-do-android-projects-cost-less-than-ios-christian-baune